# Java - Resolver NullPointerException al pasar parámetros String entre métodos

Tags: java

soy nuevo en Java, quería pedir algunos consejos de programación, he tenido problemas a la hora de pasar un parámetro de un método a otro, es cuando envío un parámetro de tipo String me devuelve esta excepción NullPointerException, agrego el código, saludos y gracias.

```
public class Arreglo {

    char[][] grupo;

    public void grupo(String[] nombres, int tamanio){
        String[] nombress = new String[tamanio];
        for (int i = 0; i < nombress.length; i++) {
            palabra(nombress[i], i);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public void palabra(String nombre, int j){
        char[] palabra = nombre.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
            grupo[j][i] = palabra[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombres[] = {"Marco","Antonio","Ivan","Daniel","Fernando"};
        Arreglo arg = new Arreglo();
        arg.grupo(nombres, nombres.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es verdad, perdon, me manda el siguiente mensaje

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at dsed_u2_ea_madv.Arreglo.palabra(Arreglo.java:25)
 at dsed_u2_ea_madv.Arreglo.grupo(Arreglo.java:19)
 at dsed_u2_ea_madv.DSED_U2_EA_MADV.main(DSED_U2_EA_MADV.java:45)
/Users/BESPRONE/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: No has inicializado tu variable `char[][] grupo` y si tratas de utilizarla te lanzará esa excepción. Tal vez esto te pueda resultar de utilidad: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42978/66587)

Comment: Muchas gracias.